# Relative layout in Scroll view is not working

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to put a scroll view to relative layout. Here some part of the layout on the upper and bottom part are to be constant. So I'm using one more layout inside,which has items that need to be scrolled.

But this is not at all happening, also the screen looks very bad with this. I am getting some black space in the bottom of the part where I defined scroll view.

Here is my xml,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logoTop"></TextView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logotop" android:id="@+id/logoTop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/bardown" android:id="@+id/barDown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_height="40dip">
</ImageView>

<ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnMap" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:src="@drawable/map"
    android:background="@drawable/mapselector" android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/utBtn" android:background="@drawable/utilitiesicon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/barDown" android:src="@drawable/utilityselector"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip">
</ImageButton>

 <ScrollView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
  android:layout_above="@+id/barDown"
  android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/tour" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/abtHome" android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
    android:src="@drawable/abouthome" android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:maxWidth="230dip"
    android:layout_height="230dip">
</ImageView> 

<ListView android:id="@+id/tourList" android:layout_below="@+id/abtHome"
    android:scrollbars="none" android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_above="@+id/barDown"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:isScrollContainer="false">
</ListView> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/tourcity" android:layout_above="@+id/tourList"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="25dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:editable="false" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip" android:background="#80000000" android:gravity="center"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/arrowselector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/barDown"
    android:id="@+id/btnBack" android:background="@drawable/arrowleft" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="6dip"></ImageButton>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Any answer for this?

Comment: cant you use LinearLayout and try this in place of RelativeLayout?

Comment: How many items do you have in your `ListView`? Anyway, I think the problem might come from including a `ListView`, who already have a scroll, inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Adinia, yes. Even I do feel the same. If that is the case, do you have any suggestion? There are 3 items in the list view

Comment: @Android Killer, no the items are relative to one another, so I cannot use Linear Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It is not good to fit the list view inside scroll view. So what I did is, placed 1 text view and image view in one xml and inflate that in List Adapter.

I placed these 2 fields in another xml say listbox2.xml

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/abtHome" android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
    android:src="@drawable/abouthome" android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:maxWidth="230dip"
    android:layout_height="230dip">
</ImageView> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/tourcity" android:layout_below = "@+id/abtHome"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="25dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:editable="false" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip" android:background="#80000000" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
```

Now inside my list adapter, am doing like this

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(position == 0) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listbox2, null);
        TextView cityLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tourcity);
        cityLabel.setText("Some Text");
        return convertView;
    }

    else if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listbox, null);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.view1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        holder.index = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.index);
        holder.desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.priceBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prcBtn);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        return convertView;
 }
```

If the position is 0, I am inflating this new xml where I kept the above 2 fields or else it continues in a normal way.

Hope my answer is clear

Answer (score 2):

Setting scrollView height to wrap_content or fill_parent wouldn't make much difference.
try

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: I tried including this. Now look wise the screen is appearing as it supposed to be. But at this point, the default scroll of list view is also removed.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "default scroll of list view"?

Comment: btw, list view only starts scrolling after the items inside won't fit the list view area anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From the description you have given to your problem, it seems that your ScrollView height should be fillParent

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occur because trying to include `ListView` in `ScrollView`, so here is a solution without the ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logoTop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logotop" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/barDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bardown" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mapselector"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/map" >
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/abtHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
        android:maxWidth="230dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/abouthome" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/utBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/barDown"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/utilitiesicon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/utilityselector" >
    </ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tourcity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tourList"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:editable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dip" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tourList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/barDown"
        android:layout_below="@+id/abtHome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/barDown"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/arrowleft"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowselector" >
    </ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Because I don't have all the resources, I can't really see how it looks, but I suppose you can adjust some more the layout settings of the views as you wish.

Comment: but with this, the layout does not scroll right? I want the whole fileds inside the relative layout to be scrolled at once

Comment: I am able to scroll only the list. But I want other fields also to be  to scrolled with the list

Comment: Well, I am sorry, but that doesn't seem possible; but maybe, if your list has always only 3 rows, you could use a TableView with 3 rows instead!? and put the image, picture, and table inside the ScrollView.

Comment: Hey, I din mean 3 fields as rows. Rows will be adding to list view dynamically, it is not fixed

Comment: You can add rows dynamically in a TableView, too, but it's not too easy to implement all the functionalities of a list. Another idea would be to set the tourcity text and abtHome image as header/footer of list.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is very confusing...
At a minimum, I can distinguish the following observations:

- Used conflicting tags.
  For example in "btnMap" element:

  ```
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  ```
- The elements of the internal layer are aligned with respect to elements of senior layer. 
  For example "abtHome", wich located inside ScrollView is aligned with respect to "logoTop", wich located at upper level (at the same as ScrollView).
- ListView is used inside ScrollView. If you want to add the top or bottom of ListView views, which differ from ListView items, but that must to scroll with items of ListView, you must use [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and [addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) methods of ListView.

General advice:
Better structuring a markup. Identify the main elements of the highest level of abstraction, and then fill them.

In your case I would do something like this (if I correctly understand what you wanted to achieve):

This is just skeleton of layout and ViewGroup you must replace with a more appropriate containers.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ViewGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <!-- logoTop here -->
    </ViewGroup>

    <ViewGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- ListView and maybe some overlaying views here -->
    </ViewGroup>

    <ViewGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <!-- barDown here -->
    </ViewGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```